# How did someone discover LCM?

Tags: arithmetic, math-history

How did someone came up with an idea that if we do prime factorization of two numbers and then multiply all the prime factors but including common ones only once, we will get a number that is the least common multiple of these two numbers?

Comment: You could probably see it as an intersection of two arrays

Comment: Observe that for a number $n$ to be a multiple of another one $m$, in term of its prime decomposition, $n$ must have all the primes in $m$ and at least with the same power. So for a number to be a multiple of two integers $a$ and $b$ it must have all the prime of both of them and if some prime is common to both factorizations, then the exponent in the multiple must be bigger than (or equal) to both. Now, if we want the least multiple of both, you just take the exponents as little as possible but mantaining everything I've said before.

Comment: LCM is so fundamental I would guess that several people had the same idea independently. Imagine you and I are both doing repetitive jobs; you take 4h to complete one job; I take 6h to complete one job. We start doing jobs at the same instant, but after the first job we're obviously desynchronised. How much time will pass until we are synchronised again, ie we finish a job simultaneously?

Comment: Least common multiples predate unique factorization by nearly 2000 years. The geometry of least common multiples is easy to motivate. Take two integer length segments, call them $A$ and $B$ and assume without loss of generality that $A < B$. Now we take multiples of $A$ until $n_1A \geq B$. If $n_1A=B$ then $B$ is the least common multiple. Otherwise we now add another $B$ and repeat until we get $n_2A \geq 2B$. Repeat this process until we find some $n$ and some $m$ so that $nA = mB$ and call it the least common multiple.

Comment: Alternatively, you and I are tiling two parallel corridors. You're using 40cm tiles and I'm using 60cm tiles. What is the smallest length that we can tile so that our tiles synchronise?

Comment: " if we do prime factorization of two numbers and then multiply all the prime factors but including common ones only once..." : Your assertion is wrong.  counter-example is (6,18).  Easiest approach is lcm$(a,b) = \dfrac{a \times b}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}.$

Comment: @Stef 120 cm. I get what you are saying but my primary question is that, how did someone thought that we need to do prime factorization of the numbers and then multiply all the factors to get the least common multiple and that we need to  common factors only once? I know this question my sound very silly but I am new to math, a total beginner and I hope I can understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to add up the two fractions:
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$$
what would you do? you could make the denominator of both sides 8, but you wouldn't do that, naturally most people don't want the fractions to get too big so they would just multiply the numerator and denominator of the first one by $2$. you would look for what's lacking. this is something many people do before they learn what LCM even is. it's a pretty natural thing to consider.

Comment: I get what you are saying but my primary question is that, how did someone thought that we need to do prime factorization of the numbers and then multiply all the factors to get the least common multiple and that we need to common factors only once? I know this question my sound very silly but I am new to math, a total beginner and I hope I can understand this

Comment: @Steve you don't "multiply all common factors only once". you write the prime factorization of the two numbers then look at what's lacking from each side, for example: $a=2*(3^3)*7*11$ and $b=3*5*2$. think of it like you're finding a common denominator. $b$ has a $5$ but $a$ doesn't, so you multiply $a$ by $5$. on the other hand, $a$ has two extra $3$'s, one $7$ and one $11$ which $b$ doesn't have, so you multipy $b$ by $(3^2)*7*11$. you get a common denominator which is $2*(3^3)*7*11*5$. this is the same thing as LCM.

Comment: I understand now. Here's my conclusion, please correct me if I am wrong.

The LCM of any two numbers must include factors of both the numbers. And the LCM should be evenly divisible by these two numbers.

Since we want the LCM to be a multiple of both the numbers and also we want the least possible common multiple, we multiply all the factors of the two numbers, where the factors which are common for both the numbers are considered only once because we want the "Least" common multiple.

Comment: yes, that's correct. you only multiply by what you have to (to make it a multiple) and nothing else (to make it the least possible value).

Comment: Thank you so much! The question was very silly and weird but it is a very big help